# android opening a new activity and return

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I have a simple android app and it has a main page with a button that leads to the second page , the second page has two buttons: button_1 and button_2. and the problem is when I click button_1 to open a new activity and then return and click button_2 the app freezes for a few seconds and goes to the main page.

I think the reason of the problem is when I click button_1 to open a new activity I have to finish this activity in someway before I return but I don't know how?

I am using a simple code to open new activity using button:

```
 Button enterBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button1);
 enterBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent in = new Intent(secondPage.this, newPage.class);
        startActivity(in);
        }   
    });
```

Comment: what your want exactly?if second page is having 2 buttons button1 and button2.onclick of button2 your app is freezing.is there any relevance of button1 click?What's is the code of button2 onclick?

Comment: @yuva ツ in the second there are two button if I clicked any of them first and return to click the other one it freezes and goes to the main page of the app.

Comment: Post your complete code

Comment: @yuva ツ my code is very simple in the second page I have two button codes just like what I added in the question and button_1 and button_1 leads to a page the contain textView only.

Comment: i just wanted know what you have wrote on click of button2

Comment: @yuva ツ I found the solution finally

Answer (score 0):

Finsh the activity using the onPause method so that once to exit/go back the method it will execute the finsh() method which kills the activity. Do this for your two child activities and this will solve the freezing error.

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it gives me this error message:   Syntax error on token "void", @ expected